# UPDATED: How to convert/parse a str date from a dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dask, dask-dataframe

Update:

I was able to perform the conversion. The next step is to put it back to the ddf.

What I did, following the book suggestion are:

1. the dates were parsed and stored as a separate variable.
2. dropped the original date column using

```
ddf2=ddf.drop('date',axis=1)
```

3. appended the new parsed date using assign

```
ddf3=ddf2.assign(date=parsed_date)
```

the new date was added as a new column, last column.

**Question 1**: is there a more efficient way to insert the parsed_date back to the ddf?

**Question 2**: What if I have three columns of string dates (date, startdate, enddate), I am not able to find if loop will work so that I did not have to recode each string dates. (or I could be wrong in the approach I am thinking)

**Question 3** for the date in 11OCT2020:13:03:12.452 format, is this the right parsing: "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S" ? I feel I am missing something for the seconds because the seconds above is a decimal number/float.

Older:

I have the following column in a dask dataframe:

```
ddf = dd.DataFrame({'date': ['15JAN1955', '25DEC1990', '06MAY1962', '20SEPT1975']})
```

when it was initially uploaded as a dask dataframe, it was projected as an object/string. While looking for guidance in the Data Science with Python and Dask book, it suggested that at the initial upload to upload it as np.str datatype. However, I could not understand how to convert the column into a date datatype. I tried processing it using dd.to_datetime, the confirmation returned dtype: datetime64[ns] but when I ran the ddf.dtypes, the frame still returned an object datatype.

I would like to change the object dtype to date to filter/run a condition later on

Comment: I think the %d%b%Y format should work for those. If it doesn't I will write some code to get the date in that format.

Comment: I found one using lambda with the following: ddf['date'].apply(lamba x:datetime.strptime(x, "%d%b%Y"), meta=datetime). But you might have a more efficient/better line. @ShyGuyRyRyNewlyTheDataGuy

Comment: If I remember right, you can use pd.to_datetime(ddf['date'], format='%d%b%Y').

Answer (score 2):

`dask.dataframe` supports `pandas` API for handling datetimes, so this should work:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["15JAN1955", "25DEC1990", "06MAY1962", "20SEPT1975"]})

print(pd.to_datetime(df["date"]))
# 0   1955-01-15
# 1   1990-12-25
# 2   1962-05-06
# 3   1975-09-20
# Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

ddf["date"] = dd.to_datetime(ddf["date"])

print(ddf.compute())
#         date
# 0 1955-01-15
# 1 1990-12-25
# 2 1962-05-06
# 3 1975-09-20
```

Comment: What other dask functions are applicable in dataframes? Is Dask worth investing a lot of time learning if I'm only familiar with pandas?

Comment: I find Dask efficient in handling my 3x8g data on my computer. When I used pandas, it took hours just reading the csv files, because I think pandas read all observations and uploads into your computer memory while dask initially keeps only a frame of your dataframe, then with functions you use, dask only performs calculation, when you call compute(), on the columns or data that you need. The longest time elapsed I exp was 5 mins, when pandas took at least 45 mins. I also tried using R, reading 1 file took 3 hours. It was hell! Some said use SAS, it took the same time,+learning curve.

Comment: thanks. The next question will be how to insert it back to the ddf?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I am having a hard time computing or parsing, I use the apply lamba call. Although some says it is not a better way but it works. Give it a try

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).