# assign a converted datetime str back to the dask df

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dask, dask-dataframe

I got my dask dataframe string date column converted to a pandas datetime and it created a datetimeindex. When I try assigning it back to the source dask dataframe using

`ddf.assign(date=date_parsed)` line, I get a

`ValueError: Length of values (1000000) does not match length of index (2)`.

I initially thought the create datetimeindex have the correct length but the source have only 2 indeces. I tried converting the datetimeindex into a pd.dataframe, which successfully converted but I cannot add that pd.df into the daskdf. I also tried converting it back to a series, but still not able to append/assign.

What I would like to do is to assign the datetimeindex back to the source dask df.

sample dask df converted from pd. all values are string datatype.

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'fname': ['dwayne','peter','dead','wonder'], 
                 'lname': ['rock','pan','pool','boy'], 
                 'entrydate':['31DEC2021', '22JAN2022', NaN, '15DEC2025']})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df)
```

what I did: (1) parsed the entrydate values and converted to datetime. it gave me the following:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-12-31', '2022-01-22', 'NaT', '2025-12-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=4, freq=None)
```

(2) I dropped the 'entrydate' column using the drop function.
(3) When I tried the assign function, I get the `ValueError...`

Comment: Noting [this nice answer](https://dask.discourse.group/t/dask-created-a-datetimeindex-and-i-cannot-assign-it-back-to-the-source-ddf/417/4?u=scharlottej13) posted on the Dask discourse, a forum for the Dask community to interact with each other, share tips and tricks, help each other with their problems, and generally be a welcoming place for people to communicate and learn.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create new column using `assign`. `Dask dataframe` supports `pandas` API, so the following works:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'fname': ['dwayne','peter','dead','wonder'], 
                 'lname': ['rock','pan','pool','boy'], 
                 'entrydate':['31DEC2021', '22JAN2022', NaN, '15DEC2025']})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# roughly same as ddf.assign(date=date_parsed)
ddf["date"] = dd.to_datetime(ddf["entrydate"])
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71251269/10693596).

Comment: Thanks, I already this method and what I get is that the result is not the same as the index.